# iDangerous swiper navigation doesnt work in iframe on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page where iDangreous swiper is installed. it works well on chrome safari and firefox, but in IE it has a strange thing where the navigation buttons dont work.
since i am using iframe to show the page with the swiper i checked the original page:

http://filmsil.com/docu-slider.html

where the navigation do work.

but once it is inside the iframe it doesnt:

http://filmsil.com/

any suggestions?
thank you!

Comment: What is the version of the browsers you are using?

Comment: @ Ashkan: i am using ie 11